# PHP Sort Varchar Data Array In Ascending Order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, cakephp-2.3

I want to sort an array of varchar data in ascending order through PHP code.
I have tried doing it, the result I am getting is :

```
ABC1
ABC10
ABC11
ABC11A
ABC11B
ABC2
ABC2A
ABC20
ABC3
```

But i want :

```
ABC1
ABC2
ABC2A
ABC3
ABC10
ABC11
ABC11A
ABC11B
ABC20
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/sort) and pay close attention to the sort flags, or have a look at [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

Comment: are you trying to sort just on basis on alphabets and ignoring the numeric values in the string?

Comment: thanks for a quick guidance.

Comment: No, alphabet will remain the same in the array, i have to sort array on the basis of numbers as described above in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myarray= array("ABC1","ABC10","ABC11","ABC11A","ABC11B","ABC2","ABC2A","ABC20","ABC3");

 natsort($myarray);
 var_dump($myarray);
```

result

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "ABC1"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "ABC2"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "ABC2A"
  [8]=>
  string(4) "ABC3"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "ABC10"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "ABC11"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "ABC11A"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "ABC11B"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "ABC20"
}
```

**UPDATE** due to discussion in comments

```
$keys = array_keys($myarray);
natsort($keys);
$newarray = array();
foreach ($keys as $k) $newarray[] = $myarray[$k];
```

Comment: in my case natsort() is not working as i have multidimesional  array:
`array(
 'BFIMO1' => array(
  'Equipment' => array(
   'equipID' => 'BFIMO1',
   'NAME' => '3000A Main Breaker- 277/480v Main',
   'location' => 'Basement- SwGear Room',
   'comments' => '3000A Main Breaker- 277/480v Main',
   'PPE' => null
  )
 ),
 'BFIMO10' => array(
  'Equipment' => array(
   'equipID' => 'BFIMO10',
   'NAME' => 'Chiller Pump',
   'location' => 'Basement- SwGear Room',
   'comments' => 'Chiller Pump',
   'PPE' => null
  )
 ),`
I am getting Array to string conversion error

Comment: do you want to sort this keys `'BFIMO1'` ?

Comment: yes i have keys `BFIMO1 BFIMO10 BFIMO2` and so on . I want to sort these in accending order.